# Retrieving total eth transaction value of block faster

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py, ether

I have written a simple `while` `loop` to return the total transaction value of a block, however, it can sometimes take almost 30 seconds depending on the number of transactions on the block.

Therefore I am looking to the community for help with a much faster way of retrieving said info.

Below is my script and I thank you all for taking the time to read - I am very new to blockchain:

```
from web3 import Web3
import pandas as pd
    
    
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(config.INFURA_URL)

block_hegiht = 13179360
block = w3.eth.get_block(block_height)
block_tranasctions = (block['transactions'])  
transLen = len(block['transactions'])
        
count = transLen
transValue_eth_list = []
        
while count >0:
            
    count = count - 1
    transId = w3.eth.get_transaction_by_block(block_height,count)
    transValue_wei = transId['value'] # get transaction value in wei
    transValue_eth = w3.fromWei(transValue_wei, 'ether') # convert transaction value from wei to eth
    transValue_eth = pd.to_numeric(transValue_eth) # convert from hex decimal to numeric

    if transValue_eth > 0: # where value of transaction is greater than 0.00 eth

        transValue_eth_list.append(transValue_eth) # append eth transaction value to list
    
block_transValue_eth = sum(transValue_eth_list) # sum of all transactions in block
print(block_transValue_eth)
```

Comment: You need to run your own JSON-RPC node locally: https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [eth_getBlockByNumber](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getblockbynumber) method receive as the latest parameter a boolean specifying if you want the full transaction object list or not:

```
1 - QUANTITY|TAG - integer of a block number, or the string "earliest", "latest" or "pending", as in the default block parameter.
2 - Boolean - If true it returns the full transaction objects, if false only the hashes of the transactions.
```

So in your code you can do something like that:

```
# I'm not sure about the python code, this is just a sample
block = w3.eth.get_block(block_height, true)
block_transValue_eth = 0
for tx in block['transactions']:
    block_transValue_eth += tx.value
print block_transValue_eth
```

And avoid doing an RPC call to get each transaction.

Comment: With the smallest of changes to make it pythonic, this worked. Tested on block with 248 transaction and your method was 6x faster than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your own JSON-RPC node locally. [See example here](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513).

Any third party node provider will give you slow lane unless you pay them several hundreds of dollars per month.

Comment: Running my own node is not the approach I am looking to employ

Comment: You will get 100x speedup.